# How to create an image of the OS  or disk?

Tags: 11.10

I want to create an image of the 11.10 into a USB or CD. I want to do a partition on my friend's laptop so I require to create the image of the disk or OS on a CD or USB.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Clonezilla.  Clonezilla is the Free and Open Source
>   Software for Disk Imaging and Cloning.  Two types of Clonezilla are
>   available, Clonezilla live and Clonezilla SE (server edition).<sup>1</sup>

For more information or to download Clonezilla [See here](http://clonezilla.org/).

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully used AcetoneISO for imaging.

Answer (score 0):

`dd if=/dev/[Hard Disk] of=/dev/[usb drive]`

I have always used this, but it will create copy image of your system.

[Other Links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19446/make-a-drive-image-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)