# Shrink down an image file which is made by with the Ubuntu's "Disks" application

Tags: backup, gparted, dd, udisks

So I've made a backup [image file from my Ubuntu system with the Disks application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171566/how-to-create-an-image-of-the-os-or-disk). My SSD storage is 180GB which is quite big due to the fact that my system is only 20% of it. So there are a numerous amount of empty space besides. I've found some [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/610819/how-to-resize-img-file-created-with-dd)s how to shrink down the .img file afterwards.

But what I'm looking for is a way or option to prepare/compress/create just the "active" part from the storage and leave the unused areas.

Therefore, to get an image like ~34GB instead of 180Gb (which is allocated the entire storage), according to the above instance.

Comment: Anything helpful in https://askubuntu.com/q/1174487/590937 ?

Comment: Well, so far the DD command might be a solution for my case. I'll take some experiment in the following days and share my feedback here!

Comment: Okay, I'm back. So I've tested that mentioned solution @mook765 , but it's very complex, therefore I'm still looking for other ways to make this task happen. Anyway I appreciate your answer! - and welcome any other too!